# Java Compilation Problems in OSX

Tags: java, macos

Code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class crypto {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String s = args[0];
        String s1 = args[1];
        String ivkey = "thisisasecretword1";
          byte[] ivraw = ivkey.getBytes();
          SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(ivraw, "AES");
          byte[] iv = { 't','h','i','s','a','s','e','c','r','e','t','w','o','r','d','1' };
      IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("ENCRYPT")) {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(s1.getBytes());
                System.out.println("encrypt: " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted)));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);
                byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(s1));
                System.out.println("decrypt: " + new String(encrypted));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'm trying to compile this just to test the new encryption methods that we're thinking of using. This is the first iteration but will be dutifully secured at a later date to implement a randomized key. Anyway, when I try to compile this I set my `classpath` in osx to the location where the `commons-coded-1.9.jar` is located. I run `javac crypto.java` and no errors. I run `java crypto "ENCRYPT" "TEST"` and just get a `NoClassDefFoundError: crypto` message. I've been screwing with this but can't see where I made the mistake. Hopefully a fresh pair of eyes will be able to shine some light on it.

Comment: so is your classpath no longer pointing to the java bin directory at all anymore?

Comment: Don't you have to provide a classpath when invoking `java` as well? Or did you set the global classpath?

Comment: I set the classpath to the jar in osx. I've also tried with `javac -cp /path/to/file.jar crypto.java` which compiles just fine. However, when I run `java -cp /path/to/file.jar crypto "ENCRYPT" "TEST" it fires off that `NoClassDefFound` error

Comment: Noticed that you are not following [Java coding/naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). The class name should be Crypto.